# JQUERY- refer to specific div each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fixed

in the fiddle you will see at the center of the page a DIV that contains text next to an img.

When I scroll down/up I need to effect with jquery/javascript only the div who's the closest to the navbar-below. all the divs as the same class so I effect them all-not what I need

For example:

what I am trying to achieve : when I scroll down,the closest div to the navbar(yellow bar) will be painted(the div) green,so if I scroll down and the navbar "collapse" with the div with will paint in green, and when he passes him and "disapper" it will go back to original color and the next div will paint in green. is it possible?

Here's the JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/nnkekjsy/3/

When I referred to div I meant this section :

```
<div class="x" id="inside_center">
    <div class="left_side" id="left_inside_center">sddsadasasdsadLorem </div>
    <div class="right_side" id="right_inside_center"><img src="http://img-9gag-lol.9cache.com/photo/a7KwPAr_460s.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

JQUERY :

I added my jquery,as you can see it works only for the first one,and then stuck.. i need to "pass" it along the others div below him when the are getting to the same point. any ideas? :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
       var navHeight = $("#div_menu").outerHeight();
        if ( scrollVal > 55) {
            $('#left_inside_center').css({'position':'fixed','top' :navHeight+'px'});
        } else {
            $('#left_inside_center').css({'position':'static','top':'auto'});
        }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for some thing like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/mcozkpv3/1/

This is just quick hack to find closes elements based on distance and selecting it. add data-did attribute to each item div.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    $('[data-did]').each(function (i, e) {
        var dist = $(e).offset().top - $('#div_menu').offset().top
        if (dist < 80) {
            $(e).addClass('closest');
        } else {
            $(e).removeClass('closest');
        }

    });


    var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
    var navHeight = $("#div_menu").outerHeight();
    if (scrollVal > 55) {
        //   $('#left_inside_center').css({'position':'fixed','top' :navHeight+'px'});
    } else {
        $('#left_inside_center').css({
            'position': 'static',
            'top': 'auto'
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: i cant upvote yet but you are awesome !!! now we have access to each element (it would be amazing if you explain the code as well so i can learn from it). now how can i access "left_center_side" div in the same approach?  i didnt quiet understand what e refers to.. i need it to be "left_center_side" div - check this website : www.10gag.co.il i want to achieve the fixed "like buttons" next to the images- any suggestions?